# execute asynctask multiple times or parallel in a loop

Tags: android, android-studio, exception, android-asynctask

**Code**

```
  for (int i=0;i<imagesURL.length();i++)
    {
        final JSONObject obj = imagesURL.getJSONObject(i);
       // obj1.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,obj.getString("source"));
        obj1.execute(obj.getString("source")).get();

    }
```

I have tried

> AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR

and

> .execute.get();

but the asynctask cause execption. i just want to execute this loop completely and when 1st task execute completely then next execute.

**Error**

```
Process: com.dexquad.posttracker, PID: 11481
                                                                     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task is already running.
                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:593)
                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:551)
                                                                         at com.dexquad.posttracker.TimelineActivity.processUserPhotosResult(TimelineActivity.java:224)
                                                                         at com.dexquad.posttracker.TimelineActivity$4.onCompleted(TimelineActivity.java:181)
                                                                         at com.facebook.GraphRequest$5.run(GraphRequest.java:1380)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThreadHook.handleMain(ActivityThreadHook.java:27)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create individual instance of `AsyncTask` inside the for loop.

```
for(..){
    //
    new MyAsyncTask().execute(obj.getString("source"));
}
```

Comment: dude you are a life saviour, that was dumb mistake .

Comment: how can i add onPost execute along with new MyAsyncTask().execute(params);

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: sorry.nothing i figure it out.